# Как работать с потоком по сети?

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, потоки-данных, vlc

Приветствую!

```
        var url = @"http://37.235.130.216:81/udp/225.50.66.94:1234";
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "VLC/2.2.8 LibVLC/2.2.8");

        int i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "VLC/2.2.8 LibVLC/2.2.8");
            webClient.DownloadFile(new Uri(url), $@"c:\output{i}.mp4");
            i++;
        }
```

В этом коде качается видеопоток IPTV порциями, размер порций неизвестен и я без понятия как это выяснить. Куски получаются размером 1-50 мегабайт.
После того как несколько последовательных кусков скачано, видно что адекватно склеить их нет возможности из-за дыры/пробела в эфире в несколько секунд(2-10), вероятно пока устанавливается новое соединение.

Вопрос: как не закрывать соединение или избежать задержки между скачиванием порций чтобы второй кусок имел начало ровно после конца первого?

т.к прогресс закачки узнать невозможно, я в тупике.

При просмотре стрима средствами VLC все идеально.
UPD: появился тонкий момент...когда по запросу webclient спрашиваю каков размер потока будет мне возращается "-1", но когда просматриваю запрос http снифером, вижу что есть параметр "content lenght" и он равен нескольким мегабайтам. Пока не понимаю как-так получается

Comment: Попробуй использовать библиотеку vlc под  .net

Comment: @adrug попутно мучаю ее, но уровень работы с сетью инкапсулирован, либо я не знаю где искать

Comment: Не в тайм-ауте ли дело? https://stackoverflow.com/a/6994391/4340086

Comment: @PavelMayorov ваш комментарий решил мой вопрос. Теперь поток скачивается один целым куском, соответственно нет дыр в эфире

Comment: UPD нет, не решил. Скачался первый кусок размером в 300 мегабайт, что заставило подумать о успехе, но затем пошли мелкие куски и дырки в эфире между порциями

Comment: Метод WebClient.DownloadFile делает то, что написано: скачивает файл с веб-сервера. Для бесконечного потока IPTV он никак не подходит. Используйте OpenRead и работайте с потоком напрямую

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Спасибо, сработало. Но не могу открыть файл в процессе записи для воспроизведения в VLC, получается воспроизвести только по окончанию записи

Comment: @Ghsee А что VLC пишет? Возможно, надо просто вызывать flush после каждой записанной порции данных.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Первое: VLC не может открыть файл «C:\123.mp4» (Bad file descriptor). Второе: рандомно закачка прерывается. Вот скрин кода: https://yadi.sk/i/tMEU-2A23U6ybB

Comment: Метод OpenWrite открывает файл в монопольном режиме, так что он не может быть использован другими программами. Используйте конструктор FileStream с параметром FileShare.Read. Метод CopyTo также не подходит, если вам нужно копирование порциями (он копирует все данные до конца потока или первой ошибки).

Answer (score 1):

Для того что бы выкачивать поток с помощью `libvlc`, вам достаточно будет указать для медиа, перед воспроизведением, правильный параметр записи в файл:

```
transcode{vcodec=%1,vb=%2,fps=%3,scale=%4,acodec=%5}:std{access=file,mux=%6,dst='%7'}
```

Где `%1` = Видеокодек `NoVideo`, `MPEG2Video`, `MPEG4Video`, `H264`, `Theora`.

`%2` = Битрейт видео потока, или же выходной битрейт видео.

`%3` = `fps` frames per second целое число.

`%4` = масштабирование

`%5` = Аудиокодек `NoAudio`,
        `MPEG2Audio`,
        `MP3`,
        `MPEG4Audio`,
        `Vorbis`,
        `Flac`.

`%6` = Muxer = `TS`,
        `PS`,
        `MP4`,
        `OGG`,
        `AVI`.

`%7` = Входной файл, с расширением зависящим, от переданного Muxer.

P.S. Далее просто запустите `Play` медиа плеер, и он начнет писать видеопоток в файл. Для остановки записи, просто вызовите `Stop` у медиа плеера.

P.P.S. Все проверил все работает.

> Upd: Добавлю от себя, данные параметры медиа, можно использовать не
>   только для записи видеопотока, но так же для перекодирования видео из
>   одного формата в другой.

Comment: помечу ответом, но пока нет возможности потестить