# Сохранить видео поток VLC C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, tcp, vlc

Требуется сохранить видео поток на жесткий диск, который транслируется на форму(WindowsForms) через библиотеку VLC. Имеется ip и порт источника трансляции(Tcp).

Comment: Это задание? Для кого?

Comment: Идите на сайт документации vlc, читайте про параметры медиа, если говорить коротко, то я уже где-то писал об этом здесь

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/808682/206435 нашёл

Comment: А можно пожалуйста кусок кода показывающий как правильно указывать эти параметры?